# What data type for storing EUI-64 address in (postgresql) database

Tags: database, postgresql, mac-address, sqldatatypes, zigbee

What would be a good datatype for storing an EUI-64 address (for ZigBee nodes)?

EUI-64 address are basically 8 octets.  From what I can gather they should not be considered an integer as such, though obviously you can make a 64 bit integer out of them.  It seems obvious then to use a bigint, though they are "signed" unfortunately so that makes it a bit messy.

I could use numeric(8), but there are no built in conversions to represent to hex (though I could write one).

I could use a char(16), but that seems wasteful.

All of these options are usable but each seems a bit messy.  I'm just wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this or a way I haven't thought of.  I am currently using bigint, which is working fine as so far.  It allows me to use "to_hex" to represent the address, but I can foresee problems unless I handle the sign-ness properly.

Thanks.

Comment: The values being "signed" would only cause an issue if you were doing arithmetic or less than/greater than comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I would write my own data type for it, using the code for `macaddr` as a template.

Comment: can you elaborate on this and provide some sample code?
Without that your answer is not very helpful